# gitlab-ci includes a file from another project that executes a script file

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I have two different projects. `project1` and `project2`.
Inside `project1`, I have `file_project1` file:

```
apply:
  stage: apply
  script:
    - bash folder/scripts/automation.sh
  rules:
    - if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "push"
      when: always
```

In `project2`, I have created the `.gitlab-ci.yml` and I have included the `project1` and the `file_project1`:

```
include:
  - project: 'namespace/project1'
    ref: main
    file: 'file_project1'
```

During the execution, `project2` does not recognize the `folder/scripts/automation.sh`. I got the following error:

> bash: folder/scripts/automation.sh: No such file or directory

Please, how can the pipeline inside `project2` executes correctly the bash instruction defined in `project1` ?

Answer (score 4):

I would clone `project1` from the `project2` job, then the script would be in `project1/folder/scripts/automation.sh`. See, [GitLab CI/CD job token](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/jobs/ci_job_token.html).

```yaml
my-job:
  script:
    - git clone https://gitlab-ci-token:${CI_JOB_TOKEN}@gitlab.example.com/<namespace>/<project>
```

The [`include` keyword](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/index.html#include) is used for importing `.yml` files into `.gitlab-ci.yml`. So, it may not be useful, here.

Comment: Hi @Richard, Thank you for your answer. 

Yes, when I clone and retreive the script (folder/scripts/automation.sh) from project1 to project2 it works. I thought there was something simpler :/

Comment: The most simple approach is to commit `folder/scripts/automation.sh` to project2, and then there's no need to clone a project. Another approach would be to curl/wget the script.

Comment: Yes I know. But this file is managed by a specific team and cannot be injected in project2, project3 ...